# Preserving Indentation on a Text Area

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have an HTML text area where a user can generate a comment:

```
  = form_for(Comment.new, url: post_comments_path(post_id: @post), method: :post) do |f|
    = f.text_area(:body, :class => "span7", :cols => 100, :rows => 10)
    = f.submit("Submit Answer")
```

When I render the comments, I use this code:

```
 simple_format(comment.body)
```

This preserves any line breaks a user enters in a post. However, it does not preserve indentation. So if a user posts 10 lines of code with varying indentation, the results will be displayed as 10 lines, but those 10 lines will all be left aligned with no indentation.

Is there any way to preserve the leading whitespace/indentation that a user enters in a textbox?

Comment: it is probably CSS issue?

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace sequences will be collapsed into one by default in html. You can change this behaviour by setting the css attribute `white-space: pre;`. You read more on here: http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score -2):

```
 <% if comment.body=~/(?:[\.]+)(/\n\s)(?:[\.]+)/
    <% i=0 %>
    <% while i <=comment.body %>
    <% if comment.body[i..i+1]=~/\n\s/ || i==0  %>
    <%k=2%>
    <% while i+k<=comment.body || comment.body[i+k]!~/\n/ %>
    <% k+=1%> 
    <% end %>
<p class="with_margin"><%=сomment.body[i..k] %> </p>
    <%i=i+k+1 %>
    <% else %>
    <% i+=1 %> 
    <% end %>
    <% else %>
    <%=comment.body %>
    <% end %>
```

And CSS:

```
p.with_margin{
margin-left: 10 px}
```

Something like this I suppose.

P.S. Do not promise this is working, but hope you got the idea